# Where to put mutable data (logging, data)

Tags: permissions, nix

New Nix user here.

I'm trying to create a derivation for `Blazegraph` from the `tgz` release available [here](https://github.com/blazegraph/database/releases/download/BLAZEGRAPH_RELEASE_2_1_5/blazegraph.tar.gz).

Inside it are multiple folders such as `bin/`, `conf/`, `data/`, `lib/`, `log/`, `pid/` and `war/`. The blazegraph database can be launched using the command `./bin/blazegraph.sh start`.

Here is my initial `default.nix`:

```
# { stdenv, fetchurl, makeWrapper, jre }:
with import <nixpkgs> {};

stdenv.mkDerivation rec {
  name    = "blazegraph-${version}";
  version = "2.1.5";

  src = fetchurl {
    url    = "https://github.com/blazegraph/database/releases/download/BLAZEGRAPH_RELEASE_2_1_5/blazegraph.tar.gz";
    sha256 = "440cecbe1714fc8eba9ec4e798f44eecb41529394323cae9027c8d1944acd9e4";
  };

  phases = "installPhase";

  installPhase = ''
    mkdir -p $out
    cd $out
    cp ${src} $out
    tar xvf $out/*blazegraph.tar.gz
    cp -r $out/blazegraph-tgz-2.1.5/* $out
    mv $out/bin/blazegraph.sh $out/bin/blazegraph
    chmod +x $out/bin/blazegraph
  '';
}
```

Afterwards, I ran `nix-build` to create the `result` folder and then `nix-shell --pure`.

Then, when I try to run `./result/bin/blazegraph start`, I get the error

```
result/log/blazegraph.out: Permission denied
```

I'm guessing that nothing can be written inside the `result` folder since it's immutable. In that case, where do I put the folders listed above (data, configuration)? First candidate I can think of is `/var/lib/blazegraph`. Any suggestions ?

**EDIT**

The `default.nix` was put inside my home directory. The output os `ls -l result` is :

```
total 49952
dr-xr-xr-x 2 xxx xxx     4096 Dec 31  1969 bin
dr-xr-xr-x 9 xxx xxx     4096 Dec 31  1969 blazegraph-tgz-2.1.5
dr-xr-xr-x 2 xxx xxx     4096 Dec 31  1969 conf
dr-xr-xr-x 2 xxx xxx     4096 Dec 31  1969 data
dr-xr-xr-x 2 xxx xxx     4096 Dec 31  1969 lib
dr-xr-xr-x 2 xxx xxx     4096 Feb 13 17:21 log
dr-xr-xr-x 2 xxx xxx     4096 Feb 13 17:50 pid
dr-xr-xr-x 5 xxx xxx     4096 Dec 31  1969 war
-r--r--r-- 1 xxx xxx 51114828 Dec 31  1969 x5p8m36z8da5zvwarjhrkh22fdk3s1hf-blazegraph.tar.gz
```

The output of `ls -l result/log` is:

```
total 16
-rw-r--r-- 1 xxx xxx 15300 Feb 13 17:19 blazegraph.out
```

Comment: Welcome to the site. Can you tell us where you installed the software? Also, please edit your question to add the output of `ls -l result` when run in the directory from which you launch the software and the output of `ls -l log` when run in the `result` directory.

Comment: @AdminBee I edit my question.

Comment: If you write a NixOS module for it, then you'll be able to setup `/var/lib/blazegraph`, but as a normal user you'll still get a permission denied error. Is there a commandline flag to set the directories for mutable data?